# DOM Exception 18 when intercepting href

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I have this little bit of code here that catches any a tags clicks...

```
var debug = Base.debug;
$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
    if (debug) {
        console.log("Caught click going to '" + $(this).attr('href') + "'");
    }
    Base.push({ href: $(this).attr('href'), extra: "Caught href from 'a' element" });
    return false;
});
```

It seems to be when ever I use this though I get `Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18`, but when ever I use just `push` then it doesn't happen.

`push` is still called either way.

I am developing using the local file system. As in instead of `http` I am using `file`.

I haven't tried it in `http` yet but I assume the error will go away according to other questions on this.

What is the actual underlying error? What is actually going wrong? Others have asked but they have only got answers on how to fix it. I want to understand it.

**EDIT 1**

I tracked the error down to:

```
return m.isLastSavedState(f) ? m.busy(!1) : (m.storeState(f), m.expectedStateId = f.id, n.replaceState(f.id, f.title, f.url), m.Adapter.trigger(a, "popstate")), !0
```

in `jQuery 1.9.1`

`Base.push` does a few minor things like storing some things in localstorage and then calling `location.assign` with the given `href`

**EDIT 2**

I don't get the error any more when commenting out the call to `Base.push` which doesn't make sense because when I call `Base.push` out of that it runs nicely with no errors. And also the click is still continuing. Returning false doesn't stop `href` from being continued.

Is there something between me calling `location.assign` and an `a` element being clicked?

Comment: There's nothing in the code above that should cause anything like that, regardless of whether you're using `file://` vs. `http://`. What does `Base.push` do? Or what else is going on on the page? Can you create a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org) demonstrating it?

Comment: What is `window.push`?

Comment: your browser will restrict data-flow only to the same: protocol, adress and port - this cannot be achieved by the `file` "protocol", you can disable this security feature though (in chrome its by starting chrome with `--disable-web-security`)

Comment: Ive tracked the error down to this line... 

`return m.isLastSavedState(f) ? m.busy(!1) : (m.storeState(f), m.expectedStateId = f.id, n.replaceState(f.id, f.title, f.url), m.Adapter.trigger(a, "popstate")), !0`

Comment: @SmartLemon: Use the "edit" link to improve your question, not comments.

Comment: So what is `Base`? Is it some library you've imported or created?

Comment: Created. The error pops up in jQuery.

Comment: So what does `Base.push` do (**EDIT:** I see your edit)? Do you still get the exception if you comment out the `push` line?